# Background image issues

Tags: jquery, css, html, image, mobile

I'm getting this issue. Also the background is going on all of my pages and I just want it at home. On the other pages however, it is showing as a banner under the `header`.

[image]

I can't get the image to work on jsfiddle but here is the **[link](http://jsfiddle.net/chadwell1028/56k0qhju/12/)**

Also, how can I get rid of that scroll bar?

```
    <title>title</title>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

<script>

    $(document).delegate('#Home', 'pageshow', function () {
    var the_height = ($(window).height() - $(this).find('[data-role="header"]').height() - $(this).find('[data-role="footer"]').height());
    $(this).height($(window).height()).find('[data-role="content"]').height(the_height);
    });
</script>
<script>

function limitTextCount(limitField_id, limitCount_id, limitNum)
    {
        var limitField = document.getElementById(limitField_id);
        var limitCount = document.getElementById(limitCount_id);
        var fieldLEN = limitField.value.length;

        if (fieldLEN > limitNum)
            {
                limitField.value = limitField.value.substring(0, limitNum);
            }
        else
            {
                limitCount.innerHTML = (limitNum - fieldLEN) + ' character(s) left..';
            }
    }

</script>


<style type="text/css">
.ui-content {
overflow:hidden;
background: transparent url(landscape.jpg);
background-size :cover;
color:#FFFFFF;
text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #000000;
}

.ui-page {
background: transparent;
}
</style>
```

```
#textarea-sendEmail
    {

    resize:none;
    height:150px; 
    min-height:150px;  
    max-height:150px;   
    }
```

```
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" >
    <h1 style="text-align:left; margin-left:40px;">Home</h1>
    <a href="#bars" data-role="button" data-icon="bars" data-iconpos="notext" data-theme="a" data-inline="true">Bars</a>
</div><!-- /header -->

<div data-role="content" id="Home">
    <p>Home.</p>
</div><!-- /content -->

<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
    <h4>Page Footer</h4>
</div><!-- /footer -->

<div data-role="panel" id="bars" data-theme="b" >
    <!-- panel content goes here -->
    <ul data-role="listview" >
        <li data-icon="home"><a href="#Home">Home</a></li>
        <li data-icon="clock"><a href="#Tee Times">Tee Times</a></li>
        <li data-icon="shop"><a href="#Rates">Rates</a></li>
        <li data-icon="action"><a href="#Scorecard">Scorecard</a></li>
        <li data-icon="info"><a href="#Contact Us">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</div><!-- /panel -->
```

Comment: Show us CSS/HTML/JS, also keep it at one question.

Comment: I linked the jsfiddle with the code. Also those questions should be related as the only time I get a scroll bar is the home page where I am trying to get the image.

Comment: your fiddle is a mess.

Comment: I cleaned it up a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JQM sets a minimum height for pages of about 230px at page load so the background doesnt fill the whole page

so you need the actual height of the window and set that as the minimum. you may need to adjust the minus 120 pixels from the total window height, but looks ok in the demo

the background appears on all pages because you use the `.ui-content` class which is used by all pages. Use the `#home` id instead so its for that content only

```
var wh = $(window).height() - 120
$(".ui-content").css("min-height", wh+"px");

window.onresize = function(event) {
var wh = $(window).height() - 120
$(".ui-content").css("min-height", wh+"px");
};
```

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/wqL5yw1q/

Theres also this method

https://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/12/01/content-div-height-css-solution/

Comment: Do you know why my home page is getting a scroll bar?

Comment: @Justin -- it doesn't initially. as i mentioned in my answer at pageload the actual content minheight is about 230px so without the code to say set min height to the windows height it will bw like this --- http://jsfiddle.net/y50ej7se/

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the scrollbar, you need to put `overflow:hidden;` on `<html>`.

Comment: That didn't change anything.